# How to animate height of control in Windows 8 XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm having trouble performing a simple storyboard-based animation of a controls height in a Metro-style C#/XAML application on Windows 8.

The following trivial XAML and code behind snippets work fine in Silverlight 5 and Windows Phone 7, yet do nothing in Windows 8 (at least for me):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="expandAnimation">
        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="scaleButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="50" To="200" Duration="0:0:1"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>

<StackPanel Width="200">
    <Button x:Name="scaleButton" Click="scaleButton_Click" Content="Scale"/>
    <Button Content="Another button"/>
    <Button Content="Yet another button"/>
</StackPanel>
```

C# code:

```
private void scaleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    expandAnimation.Begin();
}
```

The same code can be altered to animate other properties of the control such as Opacity which works as expected.

I can animate a ScaleTransform to do the scaling, but it alters the internal rendering of the control, and does not affect the layout of neighbouring controls which is a problem for me.

Hopefully I'm not missing anything obvious here, but shouldn't this just work?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just need to add `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` and then it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sofian! Adding `EnableDependentAnimation="True"` to the DoubleAnimation element in the xaml above did the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot but can you explain what this property does.

Comment: @Stilgar http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj819807#dependent explains the reason

Comment: I waste half an hour with this such thing getting crazy, thx a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A dependent animation is one that will cause the Xaml to re-layout.  Expensive; therefore requiring an "opt-in".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.pointanimation.enabledependentanimation.aspx

If possible you should use a render transform and scale the element's visual instead.  This is independent meaning that the rest of the elements on the page will not need to move to accommodate.